# koa doesn't render a page (404) after mongodb request

Tags: mongodb, koa

I am trying to render a page with something I load from MongoDB:

```
  router.get('/messages', async (ctx, next) => {
   await MessageModel.find()
  .then((result:any) => {
    ctx.render('index', {
      title: 'Messages',  
      messages: result
    })
  });
```

});

I got 404 message after I go to /messages but it works fine when I render it without approaching to DB:

```
  router.get('/messages', async ctx => {
    await ctx.render('index', {
      title: 'Messages'
    })
 });
```

Sorry for my 'noob' question, I am just making my first steps into coding. Thanks for help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `await` for models result *or*  consume them with `.then()`, not both at the same time. Try this:

```
  router.get('/messages', async (ctx, next) => {
   let result = await MessageModel.find()
   await ctx.render('index', {
     title: 'Messages',  
     messages: result
   })
  })
```